# Stop windows from compressing avaible networks by Name

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, windows-10, user-interface

Where I work, there is a massive network of WiFi nodes that all use the same name (Guest). Our network administrators do not know how to calculate how much bandwidth we need for each region. As a result, some routers have almost no web traffic and some are overloaded. I would like to connect to a weaker signal with the same name, instead of the router right on top of me. How do I get windows to show me all of the guest networks?

Windows 10 64-bit. Intel wifi card (can't remember which one)

**Edit 1:** It has been suggested that these are not routers, but APs. I looked online and they appear to be Xirrus XR-2000 and XR-4000 Systems. Will this make a difference? Also, A scan with an android WIFI app allowed me to separate wifi networks with the same Name.

Comment: Note: those most likely _aren't_ routers; they're access points.

Comment: Windows doesn't select wireless networks by BSSID, ever. Try with Intel's Software.

Comment: @grawity Thank you for that update. I will try to update the main question and I am going to add the router model.

Comment: @DanielB. Which program should I be using?

Answer (score 0):

You can download the Intel PROSet Wireless Software for your OS, [here](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking/000005634.html)

With this tool, you will be able to associate to an Access Point less saturated and farther away by looking at the RSSI (signal strength).  You can also associate to a different AP by BSSID.